# Kernel log "file descriptor" for use with select?

Tags: linux, syslog

I use `klogctl` (or `syslog`) to collect kernel log messages, by repeatedly fetching their output.

I would like to know if it's possible to obtain a file descriptor associated to the kernel log, so that I can use `select` to watch it (I am already watching other file descriptors associated to udev monitors with `udev_monitor_get_fd`, and it would be convenient to use `select` for everything)

Answer (score 2):

For kernel version higher than 3.5, `/dev/kmsg` contains all the kernel logs.
It is opened as follows:

`int fk = open("/dev/kmsg", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);`

Only fetching the latest kernel messages from some specific point in the program is possible by seeking to the end of this file at this point:

`lseek(fk, 0, SEEK_END);`

Then `fk` is added to a file descriptor set the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to configure rsyslogd to log all the messages to a fifo (`mkfifo`) of your choice, then you can open and select to read from that.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I eventually found out about `/dev/kmsg` and since the application will run on recent kernels, it will do the trick for me.